# U-SQL error in Azure Data Lake Analytics

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

I'm trying to execute a simple pipeline in azure data lake analytics, but I'm having some trouble with U-SQL. I was wondering if someone can give a helping hand.

My Query:

```
DECLARE @log_file string = "/datalake/valores.tsv";
DECLARE @summary_file string = "/datalake/output.tsv";

@log = EXTRACT valor string from @log_file USING Extractors.Tsv(); 

@summary = select sum(int.valor) as somavalor from @log;OUTPUT @summary 
TO @summary_file USING Outputters.Tsv();
```

Error:
[Erro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtGxE.png)

Other general doubts:
1. When I deploy a new pipeline to ADF sometimes it doesn't appear in the activity window and sometime it does. I didn't get the logic. (I'm using the OneTime pipeline mode)
2. There is a better way to create new pipeline (other than manipulate raw Json files?)
3.There is any U-SQL parser? What is the easiest way to teste my query?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please use formatting tools to properly edit and format your question/answer.
Codes within sentences are to be formatted as `code` 
Very Important words to be **bold** , lesser important onces *Italic*
Also use lists if necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U-SQL is [case-sensitive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-analytics/u-sql/identifiers-u-sql) so your U-SQL should look more like this:

```
DECLARE @log_file string = "/datalake/valores.tsv";
DECLARE @summary_file string = "/datalake/output.tsv";

@log =
    EXTRACT valor int
    FROM @log_file
    USING Extractors.Tsv();

@summary =
    SELECT SUM(valor) AS somavalor
    FROM @log;

OUTPUT @summary 
TO @summary_file USING Outputters.Tsv();
```

I have assumed your input file has only a single column of type `int`.

Use Visual Studio U-SQL projects, VS Code U-SQL add-in to ensure you write valid U-SQL.  You can also submit U-SQL jobs via the portal.

Comment: Also note that you can use local run with the ADL Tools in VS and VS Code to test your queries.